# C# WP8 Open TimePicker from code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, timepicker

How can I open the TimePicker to select new time but from C#? Not by tapping the control.

Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem once. I solved it by forking the Windows Phone Toolkit and making the `OpenPickerPage` of the control public.

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

(I assume you mean the Windows Phone Toolkit TimePicker control here.)

From reading the [source code of the DateTimePickerBase](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/DateTimePickers/DateTimePickerBase.cs), it would seem not.  Opening the picker page is done by the `OpenPickerPage()` method, which is private, and is only called from the `OnDateButtonClick` method, which is also private and handles the `Click` event on a private `Button`.

Of course, as the control is open-source, you can take the source code of the control and make your own copy of it with one of these methods exposed.  As far as I can tell, it's allowed under the [Ms-PL](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=131993).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was not that easy but I done that.
`TimePicker tp = new TimePicker();
tp.PickerPageUri = new Uri("/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit;component/DateTimePickers/TimePickerPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
tp.OpenPickerPage();`

The property PickerPageUri can't be null :)

Comment: @AndrewSpec I am trying to use the code your using but the TimePicker does not contain a openPickerPage() method how did you achieve this?