# Open timePicker from textbox in uwp

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-universal-app, timepicker

I want to open a timepicker selector each time the user taps over my textbox. Is it possible? How should I do that?

I found tis post: [C# WP8 Open TimePicker from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286869/c-sharp-wp8-open-timepicker-from-code)

But I cannot make it work since visual studio says that "PickerPageUri " methos is not available or not exist.

Comment: Maybe you can override the control template and show the popup manually, this is a dirty way but may work.

Comment: Why is it tagged with *windows-phone-8* if you're asking for *UWP*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to open a timepicker selector each time the user taps over my textbox. Is it possible?

Yes, it's possible.

You can use the [TimePickerFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepickerflyout.aspx) to do this, for example:

XAML code:

```xaml
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" PointerEntered="TextboxPointEntered">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <TimePickerFlyout />
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</TextBox>
```

and the code behind:

```c#
private void TextboxPointEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as TextBox);
}
```

If you want to add `FlyoutBase` by code, you can do it like this:

```c#
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{          
    TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
    tbox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    tbox.PointerEntered += Tbox_PointerEntered;

    TimePickerFlyout timepickerFlyout = new TimePickerFlyout();
    FlyoutBase.SetAttachedFlyout(tbox, timepickerFlyout);

    rootGrid.Children.Add(tbox);
}

private void Tbox_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as TextBox);
}
```

`rootGrid` in this code stands for the `Grid`'s name of the current page.

To show the selected time from the `TimePicker` in the `TextBox`, you can do it like this:

```c#
private TimePickerFlyout timepickerFlyout = new TimePickerFlyout();
private TextBox tbox = new TextBox();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    tbox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    tbox.PointerEntered += Tbox_PointerEntered;

    FlyoutBase.SetAttachedFlyout(tbox, timepickerFlyout);
    timepickerFlyout.Closed += TimepickerFlyout_Closed;

    rootGrid.Children.Add(tbox);
}

private void Tbox_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(tbox);
}

private void TimepickerFlyout_Closed(object sender, object e)
{
    tbox.Text = timepickerFlyout.Time.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank!. Do you know how can I add the FlyoutBase to a textbox by code? It is the only part I don't see how to program it.

Comment: Thank you Grace. I had to replace PointerEntered by an AddHandler because the timepicker was just shown when I drag from inside to outside the finger. Now I see the timepicker but just after I choose the time and click ok button, I see normal keyboard appearing. Also the time chosen doesn't update the textbox, I have to check how to solve this. Is there a way to avoid the normal keyboard to appear? Like disabling it or so?

Comment: Yes you can replace my event by your events.The keyboard will show when the textbox is on focus, there is no way to avoid this, a workaround method is making the textbos lost focus. And for the question of showing selected time in the textbox, I updated my answer again.

Comment: Actually, I got it working. Now the keyboard is not shown. I added this property to my textbox: IsReadOnly => true. Now it doesn't show the keyboard

Comment: @Biribu, yes, it's also a workaround, but if a `TextBox` is read only all the time, why you use a `TextBox`, not use a `TextBlock`? Basically, keyboard will be shown, when the control is editable.